# Can't access Excel file from Python and get error No such file or directory?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, t-sql, sql-server-2019, openrowset

I work with SQL Server 2019 and Python 3.10.

When I try to read an Excel file with `OPENROWSET` using this statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=\\192.168.7.9\\Import\6\strtinsertinput (4)-953aee07-ca14-4213-a91e-ab0b0f7f3db2.xlsx;HDR=YES','select * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

It reads an Excel file successfully,

But when I try to read it using Python from SQL query

```
  EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
      @language = N'Python',
      @script = N'import pandas as pd
  df = pd.read_excel("\\192.168.7.9\\Import\6\strtinsertinput (4)-953aee07-ca14-4213-a91e-ab0b0f7f3db2.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")';
  GO
```

I get this error:

> Error in execution. Check the output for more information.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 5, in 
> File "C:\ProgramData\MSSQLSERVER\Temp-PY\Appcontainer1\46CB4A4F-004A-4329-A390-FEF283444F33\sqlindb_0.py", line 31, in transform
> df = pd.read_excel("\192.168.7.9\Import\6\strtinsertinput (4)-953aee07-ca14-4213-a91e-ab0b0f7f3db2.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")
> File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 178, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 178, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 307, in read_excel
> io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
>
> Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0
> An external script error occurred:
> File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 394, in **init**
> self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self.*io)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\xlrd_*init**.py", line 111, in open_workbook
> with open(filename, "rb") as f:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\192.168.7.9\Import\x06\strtinsertinput (4)-953aee07-ca14-4213-a91e-ab0b0f7f3db2.xlsx'

How to solve this issue?

`Updated Post` : I spent more than 6 month to check this issue python reading and write locally good
but my question

Are python allow remote reading and write on remote server shared path
I need answer if possible to this question

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you should try to put `r` before the address string to make it a raw string?

Comment: so it will be df = pd.read_excel(r"\\192.168.7.9\\Import\6\strtinsertinput (4)-953aee07-ca14-4213-a91e-ab0b0f7f3db2.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")'; are this what you mean

Comment: Yes, I mean this.

Comment: it give me error PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\\\192.168.7.9\\\\Import\\6\\strtinsertinput (4)-953aee07-ca14-4213-a91e-ab0b0f7f3db2.xlsx'

Comment: Try another engine, `openpyxl`. If this does not work, I recommend to test `xlwings` if you have the possibility to install it.

Comment: how to try another engine by openpyxl or xlwings can you tell me please

Comment: `pd.read_csv(..., engine="openpyxl")`. `xlwings` is a package, you can install it through pip or what package manager you use.

Comment: why change engine are engine i use it is not available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245962/discussion-between-vovin-and-ahmed-barbary).

Comment: I think you should remove the second double slash `\\192.168.7.9\\Import\.....` -> `\\192.168.7.9\Import\....`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing pandas to openpyxl for reading operations.

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: how to wite df = pd.read_excel(file_path, engine='openpyxl') are you mean write it as following df = pd.read_excel(r"\\192.168.7.7\ExportExcel\testData.xlsx",engine=''openpyxl'')